# swift/spritekit: Is there a way to add a SKLabelNode to an SKView?

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2, xcode7

I'm trying to create a hud that sits at the top of the screen and doesn't move with the rest of the scene.  I was able to get a static view up there with this:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        let hud = SKView()
        hud.alpha = 0.5
        hud.backgroundColor = SKColor.greenColor()
        hud.frame = CGRect(x: 0.5, y: 0.5, width: view.bounds.width, height: 50)
        self.view?.addSubview(hud)
```

So with that, my player can walk around the scene, the camera follows him, but there is always a transparent view across the top which is what I think I want.

So next I tried adding things to the hud view at the top but I can't seem to figure it out. For example, if I create an SKLabel node I can't add it with hud.addChild because SKView doesn't have addChild. I tried doing hud.addSubview but a SKLabel isn't a UIView, which is what addSubview expects.

Does anyone know how I add things to the hud like labels?

Comment: Isn't a `SKScene` basically a `SKView`, and therefore, you can switch it from a `SKView` (to the `SKScene`) and also allow you to add your `SKLabelNode`?

Comment: The skView presents the SKScene. Then, the SKScene presents the nodes, which will be the label in this case. Try to use the skView's (hud's) scene to present the label node.